# Is $z^{3/2}$ analytic? If so why can't I use Cauchy-Goursat Theorem?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> $$\oint_\Gamma z^{3/2} dz, \quad \text{where } \Gamma : |z| = 1$$

It should meet the requirements of the Theorem of Cauchy-Goursat so it should be $0$. But when I do it:

$$ \oint_0^{2\pi}e^{3i\theta/2} ie^{i\theta}d\theta = \oint_0^{2\pi}ie^{5i\theta/2}d\theta = -4/5$$

Comment: It is not analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: It is not even a function.

Comment: @MoisheKohan $f(z)=z^{3/2}$ is not a function?

Comment: That's right: until you defined its domain, etc. Do you know what a function is?

Answer (score 4):

Please tell us what is your *definition* of $z^{3/2}$ so that it's a continuous function on that path of integration?

You might as well just ask your question with $z^{1/2}$ too: the square root function is more basic and exhibits the same issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to discover  with $z^{1/2}$. I think there is something wrong with zero

Comment: There is something related to $0$, but the function does not need to be defined at $0$: your integration is on $|z| = 1$, and if you integrate $1/z$ on that circle you'll get a nonzero answer, which is related to $1/z$ not being analytic somewhere inside the path of integration. Your function is much more problematic than $1/z$ since even on the *path* of integration you never told us what it means! If you try to create a sensible notion of continuous $z^{1/2}$ or continuous $z^{3/2}$ on $|z| = 1$ you'll see it's impossible. You had not thought through what you were actually integrating.

Comment: If you integrate $1/z^2$ or $1/z^3$ on $|z| = 1$ you'll get $0$, so even though those functions are not analytic at $z = 0$, they don't violate the conclusion of the Cauchy-Goursat theorem. Thus a continuous function integrated on a closed path that's not analytic somewhere inside the path need not have a nonzero integral. But your trouble is deeper, because your function (if you tried to define it first) isn't even continuous on the path of integration.

Comment: As far as I know it meets the requirements of analytic function: i*fx=fy
The problem is that if I force the module to be constant then the squareroot is not a continous function, right?

Comment: @CarlosS.G.  what do you want the square root of 1 to be?  Now what do you want the square root of i to be?  Now -1?  Now -i?  Now 1 again?  If you are not able to assign a consistent value to the square root of 1 when you continuously vary the input around the unit circle, you do not have a function.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I understand. Thanks

Comment: Before you look at partial derivatives of $z^{1/2}$ on $|z| = 1$, you should at least *define* what $z^{1/2}$ means. It appears from your post that when $z = e^{i\theta}$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, you want $z^{1/2}$ to mean $e^{i\theta/2}$. But this is not well-defined when $z = 1$, which is $e^{i\theta}$ at both $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$, but $e^{i\theta/2}$ is $1$ at $\theta = 0$ and $-1$ at $\theta = 2\pi$.  There is a fundamental discontinuity in your (hidden) definition when $z = 1$.  And at a discontinuity, what could $f_x$ or $f_y$ mean?